# Unable to retrieve posts for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For a small number of users I am unable to retrieve posts using the graph api. This happens both when requesting the post through the javascript sdk and the graph api explorer, the privacy of the post makes no difference since it happens also on public posts.

Is there any obvious thing I might be overlooking?

Comment: Users might have disabled app access to their data in general (FB call it “opting out of the platform”), in which case they are completely invisible to any app – they don’t show up in a user’s friend list (when requested via API), their post are not visible, etc.

Comment: I checked that with the user. I've gone through their privacy options and everything seems ok there.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the privacy settings "App Settings>Apps others use".
To show a user1 any information (post, etc..) from user2, user2 has to manually allow it.